# Listbox values to String in Access VBA (Separated with Comma)

Tags: vba, string, ms-access

How to store all values by ListBox in a string and separated with Commas in Access VBA

For Example:

ListBox

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

String

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: Here is where to start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.listbox

Comment: All displayed items, or all selected items?

Comment: All Displayed Items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can construct an array of listbox items and then use the `join` function to convert the array to a string using an arbitrary delimiter, e.g.:

```
ReDim strArr(0 To Listbox1.ListCount - 1) As String
Dim strRtn As String
Dim i As Integer

For i = 0 To UBound(strArr)
    strArr(i) = Listbox1.ItemData(i)
Next i
strRtn = Join(strArr, ",")
```

Or, for selected items, you might use:

```
Dim strRtn As String
Dim n As Integer
n = Listbox1.ItemsSelected.Count - 1

If n >= 0 Then
    ReDim strArr(0 To n) As String
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To n
        strArr(i) = Listbox1.ItemData(Listbox1.ItemsSelected(i))
    Next i
    strRtn = Join(strArr, ",")
End If
```

In all of the above, change `Listbox1` to the name of your listbox form control.

Answer (score 0):

You can build the string this way

**In Excel:**

```
Private Sub ShowItems()
  Dim sList As String
  Dim nIndex As Integer

  For nIndex = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    sList = sList & ListBox1.List(nIndex) & ","
  Next
  sList = Left$(sList, Len(sList) - 1)

  MsgBox sList
End Sub
```

**In Access:**

```
Private Sub ShowItems()
  Dim sList As String
  Dim nIndex As Integer

  For nIndex = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    sList = sList & ListBox1.ItemData(nIndex) & ","
  Next
  sList = Left$(sList, Len(sList) - 1)

  MsgBox sList
End Sub
```

Comment: Error in:
sList = sList & ListBox1.List(nIndex) & ","

.List not acceptance in vba :(

Comment: Ah ok - I updated the answer. Tested it in Access and it works. Ooops looks like i was too late lol

Comment: thank you!
Correct the new code.

I have a new problem: If select item, for example:

1
5
3 ---- this item
7

How to delete value in a table with "3".

Save value in a variable?

Comment: That is outside of the scope of your question. You would be better off creating a new question. Keep in mind that the answers we give are used by other people in the future, so no one else who wonders how to do this additional item is going to be able to find it using your previous question.